# How to use an union of array and parametric NTuple as function argument type in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I am trying to write a function that takes an argument that can be a tuple or an array. This works for example:

```
julia> temp(x::Union{Vector{Int64},NTuple{4,Int64}}) = sum(x)
temp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp((3,1,5,4))
13

julia> temp([3,1,5,4])
13
```

On the other hand, when I try to use a tuple of an unspecified length, it fails for the array:

```
julia> temp(x::Union{Vector{Int64},NTuple{N,Int64}}) where N = sum(x)
temp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp([3,1,5,4])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching temp(::Array{Int64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  temp(::Union{Array{Int64,1}, Tuple{Vararg{Int64,N}}}) where N at REPL[1]:1

julia> temp((3,1,5,4))
13
```

Is this not the way of doing things? I realise that I can solve this using multiple dispatch:

```
julia> temp(x::Vector{Int64}) = sum(x)
temp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp(x::NTuple{N,Int64}) where N = sum(x)
temp (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> temp((3,1,5,4))
13

julia> temp([3,1,5,4])
13
```

but I am trying to understand how `Union` works in julia, and wondering if there is a way to achieve this using it.

Comment: You can use the following signature `temp(x::Union{Vector{Int64},NTuple{N,Int64}  where N})`.

Comment: Hi @Bogumil, I'd suggest giving your responses as answers rather than comments. Even if they are very short and to the point, it will help people know that there's an answer here when they're searching for similar questions later. And since you seem to have the best answers for Julia questions anyway (at least whenever StefanKarpinski doesn't show up himself :), it'll save you the effort of then copy pasting the info into an answer later!

Comment: I thought that such short answers are typically given in comments, but point taken. I will elaborate below :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior differs between Julia 0.6.3 and Julia 0.7-alpha. What we have in Julia 0.7-alpha is more consistent as location of `where` clause does not matter in this case.

#### Case of Julia 0.6.3

You have two ways to fix the problem by moving `where` clause inside function definition:

```
julia> temp1(x::Union{Vector{Int64},NTuple{N,Int64}} where N) = sum(x)
temp1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp1([3,1,5,4])
13

julia> temp1((3,1,5,4))
13

julia> temp2(x::Union{Vector{Int64},NTuple{N,Int64} where N}) = sum(x)
temp2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp2([3,1,5,4])
13

julia> temp2((3,1,5,4))
13
```

also you can avoid the need to specify `where N` by using `Vararg` like this:

```
julia> temp3(x::Union{Vector{Int64}, Tuple{Vararg{Int64}}}) = sum(x)
temp3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp3((3,1,5,4))
13

julia> temp3([3,1,5,4])
13
```

#### Case of Julia 0.7-alpha

Your function will just work:

```
julia> temp(x::Union{Vector{Int64},NTuple{N,Int64}}) where N = sum(x)
temp (generic function with 1 method)

julia> temp([3,1,5,4])
13

julia> temp((3,1,5,4))
13
```

also `temp1`, `temp2` and `temp3` will work.